# Can both NICs be in the same subnet?

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager

I have a requirement for which I have to put both the interfaces(eth0 and wlan0)   of Ubuntu 12.04 PC in the same subnet. As far as I understand, this should not create a problem but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. NICs can be in the same subnet. In fact, the [linux bonding driver](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding) provides a method for aggregating multiple network interfaces into a single logical bonded interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can.

In the default configuration all the traffic is going to be route to one NIC, unless you modify your route table, but it should work.

I had done that (by error) a couple of times in my laptop, having both wireless and wired connections at the same time without problem.